# How do you make faster A.P.I calls using multithreading without using requests in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I'm trying to receive historical stock data for every company in the S&P 500. The problem is that it is taking a really longtime to get the data.

```
from ApiStuff import ApiStuff
import fundamentalanalysis as fa
import pickle

tickers = pickle.load(open('S&P500_TICKERS.dat','rb'))

api_key = ApiStuff.api_key
data_from_tickers = []

for ticker in tickers:
    balance_sheet_annually  = fa.balance_sheet_statement(ticker, api_key, period="annual")
    data_from_tickers.append(balance_sheet_annually)
```

I tried searching on the internet on how to speed it up but they use other modules (i.e requests, aiohttp) for making the retrieval of the data faster and I am dependent on this module (fundamentalanalysis) to retrieve fundamental data.

Is there a way for me to still use this module and make api requests faster via the methods described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can do this with multiple processes; [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) is made for this type of need. On the other hand, this is also a great learning opportunity for the use of open source. The source for `fundamentalanalysis` is available on [Github](https://github.com/JerBouma/FundamentalAnalysis). The function you're using, [`balance_sheet_statement`](https://github.com/JerBouma/FundamentalAnalysis/blob/51e5e08e1d74bb9a75b9f2b32578c75c0ea30a71/fundamentalanalysis/financial_statements.py#L62-L114), is very straightforward and basically consists of a `GET` request, a couple of data mappings, and the construction of a Pandas dataframe.

Replicating this logic using `aiohttp` or `requests` is going to be easier than wrangling the multiprocessing modules!

Answer (score 1):

If `fundamentalanalysis` supports multithreading, it can be done by replacing the for-loop with:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as e:
    data_from_tickers = list(e.map(lambda t: fa.balance_sheet_statement(t, api_key, period="annual"), tickers))
```

The maximum number of workers can be adjusted.